# call multiple Items in one loop

Tags: vb.net

In the small project I'm currently working on I have multiple Textboxes I control that all have very similar names (seg11, seg21, se31 etc.) that all use the same function. Is it possible to somehow call them all with a for loop?
I think it should look something like this but I'm not sure how I can make the different TextBox names work:

```
  For n As Integer = 0 To 5
        i = n
        function(seg"n"1)
    Next
```

Comment: `Controls.Find($"seg{n}", True).FirstOrDefault()`. See [Control.ControlCollection.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=net-5.0) Method.

Answer (score 0):

You can get controls by with use parental control control function whose parameter can be the name of the desired control.
The correct way to string concat, use the & symbol, e.g: "seg" **&** n **&** "1"

The correct code for your problem:

```
    For n As Integer = 0 To 5
        Dim ctr As Control = Me.Controls("seg" & n & "1")
        If ctr IsNot Nothing Then
            Debug.WriteLine(ctr.Text)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].